Angular routing not loading component properly
I have a problem regarding angular routing not loading my component the first time.
Example:
When i write "http://localhost:4200" i getting redirected to "http://localhost:4200/ENU" which is correct, but then my login component is not loaded correctly, im just getting a blank website with the url of "http://localhost:4200/ENU". And then when i refresh my browser,the login component is loaded correctly.
this is my routing setup in angular:
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'ENU', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: ':language', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: ':language/home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: ':language/trucks', component: TrucksComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'ENU', pathMatch: 'full'},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}

This is Angular v16
Any suggestions?
I want to load my login component when i write "http://localhost:4200" and then getting redirected to "http://localhost:4200/ENU"
this is my auth-guard:
    export class AuthGuard {
  private _authService: AuthService = inject(AuthService);
  private _router: Router = inject(Router);

  async canActivate(): Promise<| Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree> {
    if (!this._authService.isLoggedIn) {
      await this._router.navigate(['/ENU']);
    }
    return true;
  }
}


please share the code for AuthGuard

i have added it in my edited version @NarenMurali

unable to replicate your issue stackblitz please replicate and share back!

Sorry for wasting your time, i just found out that i have this ngif "*ngIf="(translationService.translationsSub$ | async)?.size! > 0"" in my html and thats why i was getting a blank website.
I appreciate your time @NarenMurali <3
